# A PostScript File not converted by Acrobat Distiller but converted by GhostScript

Tags: adobe, ghostscript, postscript, ascii85

I have a JPEG file that I have converted to PostScript with `jpeg2ps` (the JPEG picture is coded in ASCII85 inside the PostScript file which is only a wrapper).

The resulting PostScript file is [image.ps](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iw0324kap1lxfna/image.ps?dl=0).

When converting to PDF, Adobe Distiller creates a blank image, whereas, with GhostScript, the file is converted in the expected output.

Comment: image.ps works perfectly well for me with Adobe Acrobat Distiller X, produces a PDF file which looks the same (in Adobe Acrobat Pro X) as the rendered PostScript from Ghostscript, it certainly isn't blank.

Comment: I use Adobe Distiller 20.0 (Windows).

Comment: Well X is the latest version I have and it works, seems like you've uncovered a bug with your version of Acrobat, I suggest you report it to Adobe.

Comment: @KenS: You are right. I will report it to Adobe.